# Computing apparent magnitude of Algol (Python)

Tags: python, astronomy, skyfield

I'm trying to use Python to compute the apparent magnitude of the star Algol.

Wikipedia: *Algol's magnitude is usually near-constant at 2.1, but regularly dips to 3.4 every 2.86 days during the roughly 10-hour-long partial eclipses.)*

**Where's the error in my code? I'm getting 2.2 and no visible dips towards that 3.4**

```
from skyfield.api import Star, load
from skyfield.data import hipparcos
from datetime import timedelta
import math

# Load the JPL ephemeris DE421 (covers 1900-2050).
planets = load('de421.bsp')
earth = planets['earth']

# load Hipparcos ephemeris
with load.open(hipparcos.URL) as f:
    df = hipparcos.load_dataframe(f)

# Create a timescale
ts = load.timescale()
now = ts.now()

# load Algol from Hipparcos
algol = Star.from_dataframe(df.loc[14576])


absolute_magnitude = -0.07
        
for x in range(100):
        time = now + timedelta(hours=x)
        astrometric = earth.at(time).observe(algol)

        ra, dec, distance = astrometric.radec(epoch=time)

        apparent_magnitude = absolute_magnitude + (5 * math.log10((distance.au/206264.80749673))) - 5
        print(apparent_magnitude)
```

Output:

```
2.20099154236185
2.200991542408758
2.2009915424554958
2.2009915425020647
etc.
```

Comment: I'm showing the absolute magnitude of Algol as -0.11.  Where did you get -0.07?  And nothing in here is taking into account the occultation.  You're computing a result strictly based on distance.  That's never going to dip.

Comment: -0.07 is mentioned on Wikipedia. Changing it to -0.11 results in 2.16. Could you please give some tips on how to take the occultation into account? Cause I have no idea.

Comment: No idea.  That's not a computing question, that an astronomy question.  You might check out https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/